# Cannot delete remaining windows.old repository files

Tags: windows

Since recently updating Wn 10 Pro to 20H2 I've deleted the bulk of windows.old (1909) to get more storage space. But the folder shown cannot be deleted:

All attempts to delete it or its files gives the error shown.

I have taken ownership of the folder and contents. And the files are duplicates of those already in \Windows. Which also prompts the side question: why should anything from the old version still be in use?

Storage space is no longer an issue but tidiness (and curiosity) remain, so I'd much appreciate advice on removing this folder please.

Comment: Use _Disk Cleanup_ → _Clean up system files_ → tick relevant boxes, as there should be one with something to the effect of _Previous Windows ..._ or you can do so from WinRE [Windows Recovery] or WinPE [Install USB]. IIRC, you can never take complete ownership of certain subdirectories within a `Windows.old` directory due to certain hard links that go in circles

Comment: Did that but the  reluctant files remain. I have now renamed and moved them elsewhere, which allowed me to at least delete windows.old. But the files persist in being in use. In my case by various Intel stuff like Intel Dynamic Application Loader, Intel Management Engine Interface,Intel Display Audio Driver, etc.

Comment: You also booted to WinRE/WinPE and couldn't remove them? _(that shouldn't be possible)_ What error are you receiving exactly?

Comment: Why are you manually removing files?  Disk Cleanup will delete all the files for you.  Since you moved those files, instead of just allowing Windows to delete them after 10 days, you will have to forcefully take ownership of those folders in order to delete them.

Comment: Cleanup left remanants. Like user263358 I was able to rename them and move to anywhere (I used c:\tmp) ... but they persist in being in use. In my case by various Intel stuff like Intel Dynamic Application Loader, Intel Management Engine Interface,
Intel Display Audio Driver, etc.

But at least I got shot of c:\windows.old.

Comment: I'm not comfortable with the suggestion to boot to WinRE/WinPE. Tidiness and academic curiosity apart I can live with those 6 files now that I'm rid of the windows.old folder and its 50 GB of content.

Comment: As you'll have gathered, I'm unfamiliar with the UI here! I now see that I am apparently 'user263358'? Where/when did that get assigned?
P.S. When I hover over say 'Add comment', it disappears, but remains functional. Just me or by design?